# Two conflicting readings/translations of Isaiah 44:28

Tags: isaiah

There are a lot of "who" statements explaining the actions of God in Isaiah 44 such as

> <sup>**24**</sup> “I am the Lord, who made all things, who alone stretched out the heavens, who spread out the earth by myself, <sup>**25**</sup> who frustrates the signs of liars and makes fools of diviners, who turns wise men back and makes their knowledge foolish, <sup>**26**</sup> who confirms the word of his servant and fulfills the counsel of his messengers,"

In this passage (28th verse), there are two different conflicting readings/translations.

One separates the statements, implying that God is the one who says that Jerusalem will be rebuilt. The other combines the statements, implying that Cyrus is the one that will proclaim Jerusalem's rebuilding and God is simply predicting this action of Cyrus'

1. Who says of Cyrus, my shepherd will fulfill all that I desire. Who says of Jerusalem, she will be rebuilt.
2. “It is I who says of Cyrus, ‘He is My shepherd! And he(Cyrus) will perform all My desire.’ And he declares of Jerusalem, ‘She will be built,’ And of the temple, ‘Your foundation will be laid.’”

Depending on how you read the verse, it is either God who exclaims Jerusalem's rebuilding or God exclaims that Cyrus will command the rebuilding. Does exegesis of the original Hebrew shed any light on this?

Comment: I think that this has already been answered in [your previous question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/85255/is-this-portion-of-isiah-4428-being-spoken-by-god-or-cyrus).  _Jehovah makes a series of pronouncements, including the prophecy of what Cyrus would decree._

Comment: The Hebrew does not contain an interrogative/relational pronoun, "who".  That is an artifact of the English translation.